# Roots of unity in CM-field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, roots-of-unity

Let $K$ be a CM-field, ie. a totally imaginary quadratic extension of a totally real number field $F$ and let $p > 2$ be a rational prime. My question simply is

> Are the $p$-th roots of unity, denoted by $\mu_p$ in $K$ or not? (and why?)

My feeling is yes, but I'm not sure about it and have no glue how to prove it. Thank you!

**EDIT**: As the answer in general is 'no', I'm specifying my question to:

Under what conditions are the $p$-th roots of unity in $K$? (*if* there are any general conditions), ie. $\Bbb Q(\mu_p) \subset K$?

Comment: What is $p$'s relation to $K$?

Comment: $p>2$ is a rational prime, nothing more is known I think.

Comment: Well, you obviously know that not all such primes are contained in there :) I guess what you're asking is for which $p$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)\subseteq K$?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Some CM fields contain $\mu_p$, others don't.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks for the suggestion, I've edited my question.

Comment: @BISHD You know the answer for the two most tenable types of CM fields (cyclotomic and quadratic imaginary)--do you see any resemblance between those two cases?